# php mysqli fetch array not outputting results

Tags: php, syntax-error

So im new to mysqli and I'm trying to echo out the results from a table in my database

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "juneausmashbros");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM post";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row =  $result->fetch_array()); {
    echo '<div><b>';
    echo $row['title'];
    echo '</b></div>';
    echo "\n";
}?>
```

Comment: have you got any error

Answer (score 3):

silly extra semicolon

```
while($row =  $result->fetch_array()); {
                                     ^
```